# word document not opening with Interop.Word.Application

Tags: c#, web-services, office-interop

I can't open a word document with Interop.Word.Application fucntions.
I'm running the code in a webservice which is live on a server with office 2013 32bit installed.

The code is opening a document on the D drive and it's accessible manually. and when I test it on a local pc it works so I don't know what could be an issue tried different methods and permisions but with no luck.

No exceptions or error messages are shown it just doesn't load it.

```
public bool TestMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            //Set animation status for word application
            winword.ShowAnimation = false;
            //Set status for word application is to be visible or not.
            winword.Visible = false;
            //Create a missing variable for missing value
            object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
            if (winword.Documents != null)
            {
                //yourDoc is your word document

                dynamic wordDocument = winword.Documents.Open(@"D:\12cda3cf-c4d8-4537-95a0-551e97d9a463.docx");
                if (wordDocument != null)
                {

                    wordDocument.Close();
                    winword.Quit();
                }
                else
                {
                    winword.Quit();
                    return false;
                }


            }
            else
                return false;

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment."* (from [KB 257757](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757)).

Comment: Given it doesn't actually do anything (you load the document and immediately close it, Word is never visible), how are you verifying it 'doesn't load it'?

Comment: I'm verifying it because if the document isn't loading it will output the wordDocument as null and enter into e which output false

Comment: as I can tell from a the previous comment that it's not recommended to run office services through webservice. What do you recommend on tackling the issue?